# How to "DELETE" a char * variable return by a function?

Tags: c++

The function prototype:

```
char * get_something();
```

Now we need to free the memory allocated by "get_something" function.

delete or delete []?

we have no information about the impl of the function -- array of char or single char

Comment: Unless it's documented, it's anyone's guess. You could load it into your debugger and see which of `new char` or `new char[]` is called. But my first action would be to find who wrote this and demand documentation. There's also the possibility that it's returning a pointer to a `const char*` that has been de-consted. Maybe this isn't memory on the heap at all. Maybe the pointer is managed by another third object and that object will clean it up on destruction.

Comment: Is there a corresponding `delete_something(char *ptr)` function in the API?

Comment: Its not a good design to delete in a different level than new.  Better would be `void get_something(std::string &s);`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't tell.

And the author of the function should have known better than to return a pointer to allocated memory like this.

Even if you did find out (by consulting the documentation perhaps?), you'd have to make sure that your code was compiled in exactly the same way as that function. If your `delete` runtime is different from their `new` runtime then merry hell will ensue.

Your best bet is to badger the library vendor to provide you with a `release_something(char*)` function that clears the memory for you.